# How to get absolute image position in iOS?

Tags: ios

Currently I have an image inside of a frame in my view.
I would like to get an absolute position of the image.

By using `image.frame.origin.x` I get a position relative to the frame where image is.
e.g if the frame is at the bottom I should get a large number x and y. But I receive 0 and 0 as image is right next to top and left border of the frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
CGRect absolutePosition = [image convertRect:self.view.bounds toView:nil];
```

This will give you the position in the window. If you want it referenced to another view, change nil to that view.

Comment: hm. it doesn't seem to find self.bounds